# Wither Boss Not Breaking Obsidian

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently built a Wither Boss containment room made from obsidian.  Have spawned in the Wither a few times and killed him with iron golems.  So far not a single obsidian block has been broken by the Wither.  Is this a change in the game or a glitch?

Comment: Depends on alot of conditions. There are ways to prevent him from firing blue skulls at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few possible causes:

- The black wither skulls can only destroy blocks with a blast resistance of 20 or less ([source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither#Wither_Skull)). Obsidian has a blast resistance of 6000. Blue skulls can destroy any block except for bedrock and command blocks. It's possible that no blue skulls ever hit the obsidian.
- As mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345810/wither-boss-not-breaking-obsidian/345813#345813), if the gamerule `mobGriefing` is set to `false`, mobs won't be able to pick up or destroy items ([source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/gamerule)). Try running the command `/gamerule mobGriefing true` and see if that does it.
- If neither of the above are true, it could be a glitch or bug. If it continues occurring, you can report it [here](https://minecraft.net/en-us/bugs).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a glitch or the mobgriefing gamerule set to false. The blue wither skull projectiles are suppose to be able to break any blocks besides bedrock or command blocks.

Comment: Oof. I thought obsidian was supposed to be able to stop it anyway.